# Group By in SQL for column

Tags: sql

I have a query that orders by DeliveryName

```
SELECT ID, CreatedAt, Identifier, Name, DeliveryName, RoundedPriceSum
FROM StarOrder
WHERE  
   SiteID = 1 AND --StarSite.ID 1= SE, 2 = NO
   ShippingTypeID = 4 -- StarShippingType.ID 4 = STORE_PICKUP SE, 10 = STORE_PICKUP NO
   and CreatedAt between '2015/01/11' and '2016/05/30'
Order BY DeliveryName DESC
```

I am trying to group so that each Delivery Name has a total number of rows, but having no luck. Any help would be great.

Comment: Some sample table data and the expected result, and all will be much clearer!

Comment: Refer [W3Schools SQL Group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting all columns including ID (having lowest granularity or detailed data) then how can you get grouped data. Also you are not using group by clause.
You need to select grouping column and summary data like sum() or avg() count() etc. to achieve this.

```
SELECT DeliveryName, count(*)
FROM StarOrder
WHERE  SiteID = 1 
AND ShippingTypeID = 4 
and CreatedAt between '2015/01/11' and '2016/05/30'
group by DeliveryName 
Order BY DeliveryName DESC
```

For example if you want to group students by class you will select **class** and **number of student**. But if you selected **class** and **name of student** then you will get row for each student.

Comment: OP does not want sum of RoundedPriceSum, _"trying to group so that each Delivery Name has a total number of rows"_

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the number of rows grouped by DeliveryNAme this way

```
SELECT DeliveryName, count(*)
FROM StarOrder
WHERE  SiteID = 1 
AND ShippingTypeID = 4 
and CreatedAt between '2015/01/11' and '2016/05/30'
group by DeliveryName    
Order BY DeliveryName DESC
```

Comment: I get this error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: It is ok I fixed it. Thanks for the answer! Just needed a slight tweak

Comment: @Deano you ask me for an error sintax and mark as accepted  another ( stolen answer) .. with worng code ...this in not fair